# ¿Por qué no recibo datos cuando llamo desde Angular 2 a mi API Nodejs que consulta una BD SQL Server?

Tags: nodejs, angularjs-2.0

buenas noches a todos. Tengo una aplicación Angular2 que consulta una API hecha en NODE.JS. Esta API utiliza el paquete MSSQL.JS para consultar mi base de datos en SQL SERVER.
El problema que estoy teniendo es que en el componente de Angular 2 no recibo el JSON que devuelve la API, sin embargo si en el navegador coloco la ruta de la API sí me devuelve datos.

Mi API:

```
const sql = require('mssql');
const bd = require('./sqlServer');

module.exports = (app, ruta) => {
  const conn = new sql.Connection(bd.config);
  const reqSQL = new sql.Request(conn);
  let respuesta = {};
  conn.connect((err) => {
    if(err){
        console.log("Error al conectar la BD: " + err);
        return;
    }
  })


 app.get(`${ruta}/produccion/:cs/:cr`, (req, res) => {
    reqSQL.query(`Select top 3 * from produccion where cs=${req.params.cs} and cr=${req.params.cr} and activo=1`)
        .then(recordset =>{
            res.json(recordset);
        })
        .catch(err =>{
            console.log("No se pudo consultar")
        })

});
```

MI SERVICIO EN ANGULAR 2:

```
import { ProduccionService } from './../servicios/produccion.service';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';
import { Component, OnInit, Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { ProduccionModel } from './../modeloDatos';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})

export class AppComponent implements OnInit {

  produccion: ProduccionModel[];

  constructor(private produccionService: ProduccionService){};

  ngOnInit(){
    this.produccionService.getProduccion$().subscribe((prod) => {
      this.produccion = prod;
    });   
  }
}
```

En el objeto "prod" dentro de la suscripción del observable obtengo "undefined". Con algunos console.log() dentro del servicio y de la API, pude darme cuenta que el console.log() de mi componente se imprime en consola antes que el del servicio, por lo que entiendo que hay algun delay en el servicio. El servicio tiene una promesa, pero no le encuentro la vuelta para hacerlo funcionar.
No se si está bien la promesa, o si estoy consumiendo bien el observable. Por esta razón solicito ayuda a la comunidad.

Desde ya les agradezco mucho, un saludo Pablo

Comment: ¿Ya solucionaste el problema?

Answer (score 0):

Si no proporcionas también el código del servicio en el que se realiza la petición no se te podrá ayudar correctamente con dicho problema. Ya que la segunda pieza de código que has puesto no es el servicio, es el componente donde se ejecuta el servicio.